# How to print first 5 rows of all the tables in an oracle database (schema)?

Tags: sql, oracle, data-dictionary

I want to open a database (schema) which holds about 100 tables,
Once it's opened I would like to print the top 5 rows of all the tables along with their column names.

My first step was to try and get the schema and table names in the database. 
so this is what I used for that.

```
SELECT owner, table_name
  FROM all_tables
```

The expected result will contain the table name, column names and top 5 rows of the table.

I am using Oracle SQL Developer ( Oracle database)

Comment: TOP 5 rows? how to identify the top rows as it may be the different calculation for all tables. top n rows generally contain column names based on which you can order the rows and give top n rows. like Top 5 employee based on the salary.

Comment: I just want to see any 5 rows in the table just to figure out the contents of the table that's all.

Comment: Why not just browse ad hoc the tables in SQL developer?

Comment: I have to look for specific info on a table without knowing the table name. Thats the reason I need to check all tables to find out i which table holds the data I am looking for. Like I said there is over 100 table and difficult to browse all of them indivdually.

Comment: When you get your output back from your answer below, let me know how easy it is to browse vs clicking down your connection tree, one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this if you're running Oracle 12c and above.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF
DECLARE
     x SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
     FOR tabs IN ( SELECT rownum as rn,owner,table_name
                   FROM all_tables where owner='HR'
                   and ROWNUM < 10
                 ) LOOP


 OPEN x FOR 'SELECT '''|| tabs.owner||'.'|| tabs.table_name||''' 
     as "table" FROM DUAL';

 dbms_sql.return_result(x);

          OPEN x FOR 'select * from '
                     || tabs.owner
                     ||'.'
                     || tabs.table_name
                     || ' FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY ';

          dbms_sql.return_result(x);
     END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Output

```
table
----------
HR.REGIONS

 REGION_ID REGION_NAME
---------- -------------------------
         1 Europe
         2 Americas
         3 Asia
         4 Middle East and Africa

table
------------
HR.LOCATIONS

LOCATION_ID STREET_ADDRESS                           POSTAL_CODE  CITY                           STATE_PROVINCE            CO
----------- ---------------------------------------- ------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------- --
       1000 1297 Via Cola di Rie                     00989        Roma                                                     IT
       1100 93091 Calle della Testa                  10934        Venice                                                   IT
       1200 2017 Shinjuku-ku                         1689         Tokyo                          Tokyo Prefecture          JP
       1300 9450 Kamiya-cho                          6823         Hiroshima                                                JP
       1400 2014 Jabberwocky Rd                      26192        Southlake                      Texas                     US

table
--------------
HR.DEPARTMENTS

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                MANAGER_ID LOCATION_ID
------------- ------------------------------ ---------- -----------
           10 Administration                        200        1700
           20 Marketing                             201        1800
           30 Purchasing                            114        1700
           40 Human Resources                       203        2400
           50 Shipping                              121        1500
```

Comment: I'll try this when I get access to 12c instance. It certainly is much less pfaffing about than my solution!

Comment: Hi Kaushik,
Thanks for the code,  I am not the owner of the tables. I just have read rights.
I would like to input the schema name so it can take that and provide the top 5 rows for all the tables under it. Hope this explains better.
Is it possible to add one more clause where display the tables only if it has at least 5 rows. So this can avoid all the other tables which dont have any content.

Comment: @KrishKk : Sure. I'm not sure how familiar with you are in PLSQL, but it will need another layer of `select count (*) into variable from thetable ` and an if condition to decide whether or not to open cursor  and return result steps. I hope you could try.

Answer (score 0):

Normally we would use dynamic SQL for this sort of thing. But it's messy to handle the output of 100 different tables in PL/SQL. So, you need to generate a script.

**Step 1:** Run this in SQL Developer.

```
select 'prompt ' || owner ||'.' || table_name ||chr(10)
       ||'select * from ' || owner ||'.' || table_name
       || ' where rownum <=5;'
from all_tables
order by  owner, table_name;
```

**Step 2:** Cut'n'paste the output into a SQL Worksheet. Unless you're luckier than I am you'll need to edit the annoying double quotes at the start and end of each line (a SQL Developer feature caused by the line break, I think).

**Step 3:** Run the (edited) output as a script and the Script Output pane will give you the results you want.

---

> Is it possible for me to feed the schema(database) name

Add `where owner = '&schema_name'` after `from all_tables`. Or just use USER_TABLES if you're interested in the schema to which you're connected.

Comment: Is it possible for me to feed the schema(database) name so it can choose the scheema(database) if not it will run on all the schema's.

Comment: I guess you're new to Oracle but familiar with some other DBMS.  In Oracle a schema is a collection of objects owned by a user. Whereas a database is the physical software and system - the DBMS. And an instance is a set or processes mounted on the database. Except for RAC, when it's different. And 12c multitenancy further complicates things. Whatever, it's always the when we talk about "schema" we mean things owned by a user. Qualifying *schema* with *(database)* just confuses people like me who are used to Oracle terminology.

Comment: Thank you for being kind APC.
This is what I ran and the ouput came with an error.

select 'prompt ' || owner ||'.' || table_name ||chr(10)
       ||'select * from ' || owner ||'.' || table_name
       || ' where rownum <=5;'
from all_tables where owner = '&ASSET_STUDENT'';
order by  owner, table_name;

output :
Error starting at line : 5 in command -
where owner= 'ASSET_STUDENT'
Error report -
Unknown Command


Error starting at line : 6 in command -
order by  owner, table_name
Error report -
Unknown Command

Comment: I am using oracle developer.

Comment: When I run this command, this time I am not getting error 
------------------------------------------------------------------
select 'prompt ' || owner ||'.' || table_name ||chr(10)
       ||'select * from ' || owner ||'.' || table_name
       || ' where rownum <=5;'
from all_tables where owner= 'ASSET_STUDENT'
order by owner, table_name
---------------------------------------------------

I get 
prompt ASSET_STUDENT.tablenameselect * from ASSET_STUDENT.tablenameselect where rownum <=5; 

one for each table in the schema.

Comment: It works flawlessly.... Thank you very much.
My expectation was slightly different but this will work. Thanks again in millions

Comment: If you found this answer helpful please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Accepted answers improve the quality of StackOverflow as a resource for future Seekers.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code which you are looking for. I have used USER_TAB_COLUMNS view so that only tables owned by your schema in which you are executing the code is considered.

Feel free to format the output according to your need.

```
SET SERVEROUT ON

DECLARE
    LV_QUERY    VARCHAR2(32767);
    LV_RESULT   VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---------------------------------------');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---------------------------------------');
    FOR I IN (
        SELECT
            C.TABLE_NAME,
            LISTAGG(C.COLUMN_NAME, ' || ''****'' || ') WITHIN GROUP(
                ORDER BY
                    C.COLUMN_ID
            ) COLS
        FROM
            USER_TAB_COLUMNS C
        GROUP BY
            C.TABLE_NAME
        ORDER BY
            1
    ) LOOP
        LV_QUERY := 'SELECT '
                    || q'#RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,VALS,CHR(10)).EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY 1).GetClobVal(),CHR(10)) FROM#'
                    || '(SELECT '
                    || I.COLS
                    || ' AS VALS FROM '
                    || I.TABLE_NAME
                    || ' FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY)';

        BEGIN
--    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lv_query);
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE LV_QUERY
            INTO LV_RESULT;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10));
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TABLE NAME : ' || I.TABLE_NAME);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COLUMN NAMES : '
                                 || REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(I.COLS, '*', ''), '||', ''), '''', '**'));

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LV_RESULT);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO DATA IN TABLE : ' || I.TABLE_NAME);
        END;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10));
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---------------------------------------');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---------------------------------------');
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Remember that SQL tables/resultsets are by ISO/ANSI SQL standards definition **orderless** `FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY` atleast requires a `ORDER BY` use as well, but to get pure 100% deterministic (fixed) result the `ORDER BY` should atleast include a columns which has a `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` key... As `ORDER BY` on only non columns values the result still can be non deterministic (random)

Comment: @Krish kk just told in his comment:
I just want to see any 5 rows in the table just to figure out the contents of the table that's all. – Krish Kk .. so `ORDER BY` clause was not included in the code.